# Visual Basic: Pick random date on a DatePicker

Tags: vb.net, winforms, random, datetimepicker

I have a `DatePicker` with a `MinDate` and `MaxDate` value.
Can I randomize the value of the DatePicker to be the MinDate, MaxDate or any date in between?

Is there an easy randomize feature on a DatePicker ?

Thanks!
Bart

Comment: If you're using WinForms then there's no such thing as a `DatePicker`. It's a `DateTimePicker`. Things have names for a reason. Different things have different names. Use the name of the thing you're using and then there won't be confusion. Also, if you're using WinForms then tag the question appropriately. No one should have to read the comments to understand the question.

Comment: As for the issue, this is a classic case of not breaking a problem down into parts. getting a random number and setting a date in a `DateTimePicker` are two unrelated topics. As always, you need to break your problem down into parts and tackle each part separately, then combine the solutions in a manner appropriate for your scenario. You use the `Random` class to generate a random number in a range. What's the range? The number of days between your min and max dates. Once you have the number of days, you add it to the min date and set the result in your control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```vb
'Random number generator.
Private rng As New Random

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DateTimePicker1.Value = GetRandomDate(DateTimePicker1.MinDate, DateTimePicker1.MaxDate)
End Sub

Private Function GetRandomDate(minDate As Date, maxDate As Date) As Date
    'Get the number of days between the date limits.
    Dim dayCount = (maxDate - minDate).Days

    'Get a random number in the range zero to dayCount.
    'NOTE: The upper limit for Next is exclusive, so add 1 to dayCount.
    Dim dayOffset = rng.Next(dayCount + 1)

    'Add the random offset to the minimum date to get the final date.
    Return minDate.AddDays(dayOffset)
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Ticks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.ticks) count between the Control's maximum and minimum assignable values, multiply by a random value and add the resulting value to the minimum value.

In a WinForm's DateTimePicker, the minimum and maximum values assignable to the Control are specified in the [DateTimePicker.MaxDate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.maxdate) and [DateTimePicker.MinDate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate) properties.

The [Random](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random) class can be used to generate a random Double value in the range `[0.00 - 1.00)` using its [NextDouble()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.nextdouble) method.

► You should declare your random generator as a `static` (`Shared`) Field, then call its methods when needed.

You can then create a TimeSpan from the generated random value - converted to `Long` - and add the TimeSpan to the `MinDate` of your Control (or use the [DateTime.AddTicks()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addticks) method).
This randomizes both the Date and the Time parts:

```
Private Shared rndDate As New Random()
' [...]

' Call when needed
Dim dtPicker = [Some DateTimePicker instance]
Dim randomTicks = CLng((dtPicker.MaxDate - dtPicker.MinDate).Ticks * rndDate.NextDouble())
dtPicker.Value = dtPicker.MinDate + New TimeSpan(randomTicks) 
' OR dtPicker.Value = dtPicker.MinDate + TimeSpan.FromTicks(randomTicks)
' OR dtPicker.Value = dtPicker.MinDate.AddTicks(randomTicks)
```

Comment: `DateTime` has an `AddTicks` method so the `TimeSpan` creation is superfluous. This is basically the same principle as my answer. If you want just the date, generate a tandom number of days and add that to the minimum value. If you want time as well then it's the same thing with ticks or maybe just seconds.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Given the *nature* of the question, I though it could have been be more interesting to show the use of the operator (`DateTime + TimeSpan`), the `AddSomething()` method was already shown in your code (I've answered because the OP pinged me directly). I've added the alternative anyway.